# Convergence in L 1

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Prove that if the $X_l$'s are i.i.d. and in $L^1$, then $(n^{-1} \sum^n_{k=1} X_k)_{n \ge 1}$ is uniformly integrable.

gb

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Lastly, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm also studying this topic, would appreciate comments on this)

A sequence $\{X_n\}$ converges to $X$ in the $L^1$ norm if and only if it converges in measure to $X$ and is uniformly integrable. In probability terms, a sequence of random variables converging in probability sense also converge in expected sense if and only if they are uniformly integrable. So if we can conclude convergence, we then have uniform integrability. Let

$$\bar{X_{n}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$$

By definition of converges in probability, we need to show that, for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\mathbb P\left(|\bar{X_{n}}-0|\geq \epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0$$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$. We have $\mathbb E(\bar{X_{n}})=0$, $\mathrm{Var}(\bar{X_{n}})=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

Hence by Chebyshev's inequality,

$$\mathbb P\left(|\bar{X_{n}}-0|\geq \epsilon\right)\leq\frac{\mathrm{Var}(\bar{X_{n}})}{\epsilon^2}\rightarrow 0$$

The convergence in probability is proven, and then uniform integrability follows.